# How can i merge code into master manually?

Tags: git

I created a branch from Master and then I check in the code for 10 times now I want to merge the 7th committed code into master.how can i do it?
(or)

I had a code I want to merge it to the master.The code is in my local machine and I got the code from my friend. Can i merge this code into master?

Comment: I have not cloned an existing repository and want to connect my repository to a remote server(Master).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your First Question as Suggested by our brother you can directly merge by SHA ID.
For your Second Question i would like add some more little  info .
first of all you need to go the Current Working Directory

Type following commands

1.`git init`

2.`git add .`

3.`git commit -m 'Your Commit Message'`

and then add the Remote Url

4. `git remote add origin remote repository url`

after you can verify it by

5.`git remote -v`

Now Push you changes

6. `git push origin master`

Answer (score 1):

You can merge any commit in your master branch: get the SHA1 of the 7th committed code of that branch (I assume said branch is already in your local clone.
For getting that sha1, look through the history of your branches:

```
git log --all --branches --oneline
```

Then:

```
git checkout master
git merge <sha1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `git remote add...` to add a required remote repository, then `git fetch` everything from that remote, and then you can `git merge` branches as usually. Use `git <command> --help` to observe required parameters and possible options